# Passing String, integer and tuple information as key for python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, namedtuple

I'm trying to create a python dictionary and I would like to use a key that contains strings, numerics & a list/tuple entry. The key should ideally look like

```
("stringA", "stringB", "stringC", integer1, (integer2, integer3, integer4))
```

I tried to create a namedtuple based on this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as follows

```
from collections import namedtuple
dictKey = namedtuple('dictKey', 'stringA stringB stringC integer1 
                      (integer2 integer3 integer4)')
```

but it throws me a ValueError saying it can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores. So

1. How can I create a dictionary key which contains a tuple?
2. How to effectively use the dictionary key (especially the tuple it
   contains) to retrieve information from the dictionary?

Comment: You can use a tuple of items as the key exactly as you have posted, the only error is the namedtuple

Comment: To the downvoter - Please suggest improvements or violations  when you downvote as I think it will help all of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with your `namedtuple` definition, not the dictionary key structure itself, which will work just fine, e.g.:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[('1', '2', 3, (4, 5))] = 'foo'
>>> d
{('1', '2', 3, (4, 5)): 'foo'}
```

When the `namedtuple` reads the `field_names` parameter, it thinks you're trying to create a field named `(integer2`, and doesn't realise that you mean it to be a nested `tuple`.

To define that structure in a `namedtuple`, you will instead have to have an attribute that is itself a `tuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> dictKey = namedtuple("dictKey", "stringA stringB stringC integer1 tuple1")
>>> key = dictKey("foo", "bar", "baz", 1, (2, 3, 4))
>>> d[key] = 'bar'
>>> d
{dictKey(stringA='foo', stringB='bar', stringC='baz', integer1=1, tuple1=(2, 3, 4)): 'bar',
 ('1', '2', 3, (4, 5)): 'foo'}
```

You can retrieve the value stored against the key exactly as you can for any other, either with the original `namedtuple`:

```
>>> d[key]
'bar'
```

or a new one:

```
>>> d[dictKey("foo", "bar", "baz", 1, (2, 3, 4))]
'bar'
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also please answer the part of question on retrieving information and I can accept the answer.

Comment: @WanderingMind what do you mean? Once you have the key, you can use it like any other. I have added a few lines, let me know if that answers the question more fully.

Comment: For example how can I retrieve all the dictionary items corresponding to say tuple1[1]=3

Comment: @WanderingMind if that's what you want, perhaps this structure isn't the best way forward. But you can get a list of matching keys with e.g. `[key for key in d if key.tuple1[1] == 3]` (assuming *all* keys have that attribute).

Comment: @WanderingMind no problem. Note that this may be [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but more information would be needed to determine whether this is the appropriate data structure.

Comment: Its actually a dictionary to store some crystallography structure information. The strings describe the different atom types and the tuple describes the number of unit cells in different direction.