# Using namedtuple as dictionary key throws error

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key, namedtuple

Related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415736/passing-string-integer-and-tuple-information-as-key-for-python-dictionary/28415813#28415813).

I'm using `PyCharm` and doing some pre-processing to build a many-to-many relationship in memory (eventually to dump to multiple CSV files). I'm using a `dictionary` as a means of testing for the existence and look-up of a primary `key` given distinct `namedtuple` data.

```
def insert_where_not_exists(self, path, tag):
    path_id = self.__tbl_path[path]
    tag_id = self.__tbl_tag[tag]

    # Invalid or missing tag, so insert this one
    if tag_id is None or tag_id < 0:
        tag_id = self.__tag_ct
        self.__tag_ct += 1
        self.__tbl_tag[tag] = tag_id

    # We assert that we have the tag stored and an appropriate tag_id
    # Create the relationship between filepath and tag
    relationship = namedtuple("relationship", "tag_id path_id")
    rel = relationship(tag_id=tag_id, path_id=path_id)
    rel_id = self.__tbl_rel.[rel]

    # Invalid or missing relationship, so insert this one
    if rel_id is None or rel_id < 0:
        rel_id = self.__rel_ct
        self.__rel_ct += 1
        self.__tbl_rel[rel] = rel_id
```

My problem is when attempt to look up a `namedtuple` (`dictionary key`) to get an associated index, `PyCharm` throws me this error.

```
"name expected" at:
 rel_id = self.__tbl_rel.[rel]
```

Comment: I assume `__tbl_rel` is a dictionary. You have an extra period in the line you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
rel_id = self.__tbl_rel.[rel]
```

is invalid syntax, it is either

```
rel_id = self.__tbl_rel.rel
```

or

```
rel_id = self.__tbl_rel[rel]
```

In this case:

```
rel_id = self.__tbl_rel[rel]
```

is correct.

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.